# Python dynamic enum

Tags: python, list, enums

I would like to create dynamic enums in python loaded from a SQL Table. The output of SQL will be a list of tuplets, which with I want to fill the attributes of the enum.

Lets say I receive this list:

```
lst = [('PROCESS_0', 0, "value", 123, False), ('PROCESS_1',1,"anothervalue", 456, True)]
```

I now want to fill the values in the enum below:

```
class Jobs(IntEnum):
    def __new__(cls, value: int, label: str, heartbeat: int = 60, heartbeat_required: bool = False):
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.label = label
        obj.heartbeat = heartbeat
        obj.heartbeat_required = heartbeat_required
        return obj
```

The first variable in the tuple should be the variable name of the enum, I have solved this with:

```
locals()['Test'] = (0, '', 789, False)
```

But this only works for single values, it seems that I can not run a for loop within enum. When using a for loop like this:

```
 for i in lst:
    locals()[i[0]] = (i[1], i[2], i[3])
```

Python sends this error **TypeError: Attempted to reuse key: 'i'** which propably comes from enums only having constants.

Is there any (possibly elegant) solution for this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get any error when running your code on Python3.

Comment: I am running code example 3 and 4 within the Enum class. My current python version is 3.8.5.

Comment: If I understand your use case, I would go for a `dict` of `namedtuple`s (or even `dataclass`es if you want to be able to change the values of the attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `_ignore_ = "i"`.  Something like:

```
class Jobs(IntEnum):

    _ignore_ = "i"

    def __new__(cls, value, label, heartbeat=60, heartbeat_required=False):
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.label = label
        obj.heartbeat = heartbeat
        obj.heartbeat_required = heartbeat_required
        return obj

    for i in lst:
        locals()[i[0]] = i[1:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about _ignore_ in class enum! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the example at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#timeperiod

Note that the `_ignore_` can be avoided in favor of dict comprehension

```py
from datetime import timedelta
class Period(timedelta, Enum):
    "different lengths of time"
    vars().update({ f"day_{i}": i for i in range(367) })
```

Then you can access all possible enum values via `Period.__members__`